# Problem with formatting tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I want to create two tables that have the same width of columns.  Both tables consist of 6 rows and 3 columns.  In both tables, row 1 and row 4 are explanatory, and should expand in all columns.  In the first table, rows 2, 3, 5, and 6 should have three columns of the same width.  In the second table, rows 2 and 3 should have 2 columns of the same width, and rows 5 and 6 should have three columns of the same width.

This is how I've made the first table:

```
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Distribution of mappings for the SLA parameter $\pi$.}
        \label{tab:distPi} \centering
        \begin{tabular*}{0.45\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|}
            \hline
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Name of the SLA parameter $\pi$}} \\
            \hline
                \emph{Cost} & \emph{Charge} & \emph{Rate} \\
            \hline
                15\% & 15\% & 40\% \\
            \hline
            \hline
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Unit of the SLA parameter $\pi$}} \\
            \hline
                \emph{USD} & \emph{GBP} & \emph{YPI} \\
            \hline
                38\% & 2\% & 40\% \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \end{table}
```

and this is how I've made the second table:

```
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Distribution of mappings for the SLA parameter $\mu$.}
        \label{tab:distMu} \centering
        \begin{tabular*}{0.45\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
                \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Name of the SLA parameter $\mu$}} \\
            \hline
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\emph{MemoryConsumption}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\emph{Consumption}} \\
            \hline
                \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{70\%} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{30\%} \\
            \hline
            \hline
                \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Unit of the SLA parameter $\mu$}} \\
            \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\emph{Mbit}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\emph{Gbit}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\emph{Tbit}} \\
            \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{5\%} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{55\%} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{40\%} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \end{table}
```

However, the formatting is not good.  Unfortunately, I can't show the screenshot, because my reputation is less than 10.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it better?  The page is two-columned and the tables will be in one of the two columns.  Their width should be ca. 90% of the width of the column.

Comment: There's a community for LaTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

I would migrate there and ask, as those people know a LOT more than the SO people (on average) about TeX.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of the ugly formatting is the way the right vertical line lies some distance away from the hlines. If you play with the table width a bit, moving it up and down, you'll see that the distance between the vline and the hlines is dependent on the argument given to the second argument in the \begin{tabular*} declaration, the width. Move it in one direction and the distance becomes greater, move it in the other direction and it becomes less until the hlines actually extend *beyond* the vline. You can either play with that number until it's placed just right, or, you can simply use the {tabular} environment, which doesn't require a width argument, instead of {tabular*}. Since you don't need the table to float anyway (as evidenced by the [h] location argument), you probably don't lose anything by using {tabular}.